# Line chart visualisation in Kibana based on month categories

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, vega-lite

Can anyone help someone who's new to ElasticStack draw what should hopefully be a fairly simple visualisation in Kibana? I've read lots of articles and I'm still scratching my head about this after a few days of trying.

Essentially I have some records in Elastic, the data structure of which looks something like this (there are thousands of these, just three shown for example):

```
{
  "user":13484,
  "january_score":43.4,
  "february_score":56.6,
  "march_score":65.6
},
{
  "user":13213,
  "january_score":38.4,
  "february_score":27.6,
  "march_score":45.6
},
{
  "user":13211,
  "january_score":54.4,
  "february_score":66.6,
  "march_score":70.6
},.....
......
```

What I need to create from this data is a line chart with average score on the y-axis and the months on the x-axis.

I had no luck in Kibana but I know I can do the appropriate query on Elastic from the console using this code:

```
GET index-v2/_search
{
  "query" : {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "size":0,
  "aggs": {
    "January":{
      "avg": {
        "field": "january_score"
      }
    },
    "February":{
      "avg": {
        "field": "february_score"
      }
    },
    "March":{
      "avg": {
        "field": "march_score"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which correctly gives me the average score for each month, response:

```
  "aggregations": {
    "February": {
      "value": 0.7077278572380574
    },
    "March": {
      "value": 0.729840163141489
    },
    "January": {
      "value": 0.6218274211539049
    }
  }
```

How can I chart these averages in Kibana?

Answer (score 0):

with that data model, it'd be very tricky because you want to use (aggregations over) distinct fields as temporal coordinates of the x-axis of a line chart. I could be wrong, but I think you can achieve that without changing your data model only with a highly customised Vega diagram ([docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/vega.html)).

If you can afford to change your data model, I'd recommend changing it to something like

```
{
  "user": keyword,
  "date": date (MM),
  "score": float
}
```

this way, you can define your x-axis using the `date_histogram` function over the `date` field with an interval of a month, and you'll get the flexibility of selecting any desired aggregation (average, median, percentiles, ...) for your score over all users.